# .mainTable TD CSS not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a CSS file with the following:

```
    .mainTable
{
    width:100%; 
    border:solid;
}

.mainTable td
{
        border:solid; 
        text-align:center;
}
```

In firefox and ie all the td's now have a border and are center aligned. However chrome simply ignores it and the td's are not formatted.

Any clue as to why chrome behaves differently?

Comment: Have you tried border:1px solid black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give the borders a width and a color, this is a much better cross browser solution.

```
.mainTable
{
    width:100%; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.mainTable td
{
        border: 1px solid #000; 
        text-align:center;
}
```

The color can be whatever color you want.

You don't see the border in chrome because it has no width.